# SQL server with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, database, unix

I've been trying to get my rails program to access an existing sql express server set up on another machine at work. I've followed these instructions: [GitHub](https://github.com/bfabry/2000-2005-adapter/blob/master/README.rdoc) and set up my database.yml like this:

```
development:  
adapter: sqlserver  
mode: odbc  
dns: Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MACHINENAME\SQLEXPRESS;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxxx;Application Name=atlas  
timeout: 5000
```

Now when I try to run script/console (or server or whatever) I get this error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:440:in `load_missing_constant':NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::WrappedDatabaseException
```

I've tried googling and changing settings back and forth but i've come up blank. Am I doing something awfully wrong or what?

BR,
SG

Comment: I know there's a lot of improvements in Rails 3, especially in the ActiveRecord realm. It might be worth trying that version to see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only speak for using Rails 3.0.3 with SQLServer 2005, so I hope that helps you a bit.

I've added this to my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'ruby-odbc', '0.99991', :require => 'odbc'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', :branch => "arel2",
  :git => "git://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter"
```

And use this in my `config/database.yml`:

```
test:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: ODBC
  dsn: my_app_test
  username: [USERNAME]
  password: [PASSWORD]
```

The DSN is configured elsewhere, but it is in nowhere as complex as yours. I followed these instructions: http://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Platform-Installation---Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks, took some tweaking but I got it working eventually. Decided to go with 3.0.3 and that was much easier than trying to get 2.3.8 to work ;)